# IPhone Repository for data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

I'm a totally noob in IPhone development. Just start a week ago. I'm trying to have this tableview working.

I have a class I created called CustomerRepository with a method like this

```
 - (CustomerRepository *) init {

self = [super init];

if (self) {


    customerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    Customer *cust1 = [[Customer alloc] init];
    cust1.name = @"cust1";  

    [customerArray addObject: cust1];

    [cust1 release];
}


return self;

}

- (NSMutableArray *) GetAll {

    NSMutableArray *returnCustomerArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease]; 

    for(Customer *cust in customerArray)
    {
        Customer *copy = [[Customer alloc]init];
            copy.name = cust.name;
        [returnCustomerArray addObject:copy];
        [copy release];
    }

    return returnCustomerArray;

}
```

Now In my Controller

```
  @synthezise customerArray;

  viewDidLoad {

    CustomerRepository *custRepo = [[CustomerRepository alloc] init];

customerArray = [custRepo GetAll];

[custRepo release];
  }


 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tv numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    // It always throw an exception here about -[UITableViewRowData count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
    return [customerArray count];
}
```

There is definitely something wrong with my code, can you guys help me point out what is wrong. Most probably an access to an instance that is already release ....

Comment: Is it possible the datasource methods are getting called before viewdidload? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484024/core-data-datasource-methods-is-called-before-viewdidload

Comment: Debugging it, shows that the viewDidLoad was called before the datasource methods

Comment: I will take a deeper look, thanks blindJess, maybe something is causing the datasource method to be called before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to retain the array returned by GetAll. Try this:

```
viewDidLoad {

  CustomerRepository *custRepo = [[CustomerRepository alloc] init];

  customerArray = [[custRepo GetAll] retain];

  [custRepo release];
}
```

If you don't retain it, then your autorelease in -GetAll means that the returned array will eventually be released. When your -numberOfRowsInSection method fires, it's talking to a dealloc'd instance.

Comment: I was literally typing the same exact answer! +1

Comment: Heh, sorry 'bout that! +1 back atcha then :-)